# XACML on an Android device?

Tags: android, authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

I am doing some academic research and implementations on Android applications. And I am looking for an appropriate policy language such as XACML.

Is there any XACML version or extension that work on an Android device?

Answer (score 0):

That I am aware, there aren't any XACML engines running on Android. XACML lends itself well to a client-server architecture.

If the XACML engine were on the device you would have to trust that the right decisions were produced and enforced.

A research group led by Bernard Butler from TSSG (Waterford Institute of Technology) also researched a JSON format for XACML policies. They may have more insight.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your kind response, I will do more investigations on XACML and its extensions and search for other suggestions as the one you indicated "JSON format". King regards!